# AccessibilityIdentifier for group of Texts at the same time with identifiers to each of Text

Tags: swift, swiftui, accessibility, uiaccessibility

For example code:

```
HStack {
    Text("Hello")
        .accessibilityIdentifier("first_word")
    Text(" ")
    Text("World!")
        .accessibilityIdentifier("second_word")
}
// Place, where I want to put "phrase_identifier",
// but it will override "first_word" and "second_word" identifiers
```

Is it possible to create "phrase_identifier" which return me "Hello World!", and in the same time to have possibility to get text addressing by "first_word" = "Hello", "second_word" = "World!" ?

Update:
Below was proposed next solution, but in result it create group of identifiers, and I can't get value or user input label or label by "phrase_identifier"

[image]

Next: what shows element
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should add `.accessibilityElement(children: .contain)` before the accessibility identifier.

```
HStack {
    Text("Hello")
        .accessibilityIdentifier("first_word")
    Text(" ")
    Text("World!")
        .accessibilityIdentifier("second_word")
}
.accessibilityElement(children: .contain)
.accessibilityIdentifier("phrase")
```

See also the code example in the documentation of [`.contain`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/accessibilitychildbehavior/contain), which is a similar situation to what you have.

You can also use the `.combine` behaviour:

```
.accessibilityElement(children: .combine)
```

This combines the accessibility properties of the children in some system-defined way.

Comment: I afraid it is not what I want to get: you see on the screenshot (I will add to original post) accessibilityIdentifier "phrase" has empty value, because "phrase" is a group, not element.

Comment: @Konstantin.Efimenko Not sure what you mean, even after seeing the screenshot. What did you expect the accessibility inspector to display?

Comment: I expect value of Label field "Hello World!"

Comment: @Konstantin.Efimenko `.accessibilityLabel("Hello World")` then. There is no magic.

Comment: @Konstantin.Efimenko Or you can use the `.combine` behaviour - that gives you `Hello,  , World!`. Do you want that instead?